# Installation condition of XP SP3 for .net application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

My .NET application requires Windows XP SP3 or above to run. So I would like to check for the OS version before allowing user to install. How can I achieve this in a VS2008 setup project or another way?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done through a custom launch condition:

- select your setup project in Solution Explorer
- go to its Launch Conditions Editor
- add a new launch condition
- in its Properties pane set Condition field to:

  (VersionNT > "502") OR ((VersionNT = "502") AND (ServicePackLevel = "3"))
- set Message field to the error message you want to display when the Windows version is not supported

When launching your package, if the launch condition is not met an error is shown and the installation stops.

You can read more about this here: http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-environment/install-resources-windows-ver/

Comment: I think it must be "501" and not "502"